# После истечения времени кэширования выводит JSON

Tags: html, json, laravel, redis

Всем привет, проект на Laravel 5.5, при кэшировании HTML в начале его выводит, а после истечения времени кэширования выводит JSON.

```
$topSevenPosts = Cache::tags(Post::class)->remember('seven_posts_html'.getLocal(), 5, function () {
    $topSevenPosts = $this->getTopSevenPostLastTwenty();
    $view = view('front.home.top_seven', compact('topSevenPosts'))->render();
    return $view;
});
```

Comment: получается будто не отрабатывает render()

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вопрос закрыт, оказалось что под тем же ключем "seven_posts_html" кэширую модель в мобильной версии.